# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo, Unable to instantiate fragment, could not find Fragment constructor

Tags: java, android

> Please see all the four pictures, first 3 pictures has error screen, the last one has Fragment constructor.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbodG.png
[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nysfG.png
[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHYCR.png
[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/telPC.png
[image]

Comment: Where are the pictures?

Comment: try to put a blank/empty constructor..

Comment: @mike  https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbodG.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/nysfG.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHYCR.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/telPC.png

Comment: @SRB i'm passing multiple "url" from different classes to this "Tab1Fragment" class which handles web stuffs...

Comment: Please add your code and errors as text and not as images.

Comment: Post your fragment code.

Comment: The trace implies that the problem could be calling a non-existent constructor method for a `Table_Fragment` class of some sort (I couldn't be sure of that as you haven't attached enough code to your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a default constructor for Fragment.

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment{

public Tab1Fragment(){
}
...
}
```

If you want to pass data to your fragment you must do that by **setArguments()**, not by passing it through constructor, not good practice.
Instead try something like this:

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment{
    private static final String ARG_URL = "url";
    public Tab1Fragment(){
    }
    public static Tab1Fragment newInstance(String url) {
            Tab1Fragment fragment = new Tab1Fragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ARG_URL, url);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
}
```

And to get url value in fragment use

```
getArguments().getString(ARG_URL);
```

Now use newInstance method to get fragment instance.

```
Tab1Fragment.newInstance("your url");
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Mangal mentioned, a Fragment must have a default (no argument) constructor. To pass data to a new fragment, use a static function, like this

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(String someData) {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment ();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("someData", someData);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

and retrieve the data like this

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    String someData = "";
    if( args != null ) {
        someData = args.getString("someData", "");
    }
}
```

Then, instead of calling

```
new MyFragment(data);
```

in the code where you create the Fragment, you would instead call

```
MyFragment.getInstance(data);
```

Comment: I didn't see your answer before, It just showed up after I finished editing my answer. I really wouldn't have updated it if I had seen your post.

Comment: No worries, I think we have consensus on the right approach :)